# Excel 2016 Return Header in Sheet 2 if Cell says "Yes" below the header. And insert it in Sheet 1

Tags: excel

I have a List of people in sheet 1, and they have Skills as column, for example Languages(Lang):

```
  Lang Skill2 Skill3
P1  x    x       x
P2  x    x       x 
P3  x    x       x
```

In Sheet 2 I have the Matrix for that particular skill and the Persons in rows (P1,P2,P3), and all the columns for the Languages (L1, L2, L3) just say "Yes" and "No"

```
  L1 L2 L3
P1 y  n  n
P2 y  y  n
P3 y  n  y
```

Now My goal is to Return the Header (L1) in sheet 2 if it says "Yes" in a below Cell for that particular Person. And Input that header in a List or just as a string of text separated by commas (,) in Sheet 1.

I want to make it as cleanly as possible, and I have been trying for days to come up with an formula. Unfortunately, unsuccessful so far.

Are you able to help me with this problem?

I am up for nearly anything at this point, even using VBA (if necessary).
Also Both tables are Formatted tables. If that is necessary to know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use following formula.

`=IF(Sheet2!B2="y";Sheet2!B$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!C2="y";Sheet2!C$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!D2="y";Sheet2!D$1&", ";"")`

You just add a new IF condition for an additional language. You can also add new formulas for a new skills with another data source.

The LEFT function cuts off the space and comma separator behind last skill. But if person speaks no language then it would cause an error. But you can update the formula in a following way

`=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B2:D2;"y")>0; LEFT(IF(Sheet2!B2="y";Sheet2!B$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!C2="y";Sheet2!C$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!D2="y";Sheet2!D$1&", ";"");LEN(IF(Sheet2!B2="y";Sheet2!B$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!C2="y";Sheet2!C$1&", ";"")&IF(Sheet2!D2="y";Sheet2!D$1&", ";""))-2);"")`

Then the cell is left blank in case person has no skill.

Plese look at [my example sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvP6NwTpIPzsmMEHQhI9iblODacP1Q) where you can see an example output for your data.

**Edit #1**

I did not realize that for US language settings there is a comma as a default list separator. So the updated formula for default US locale is this one:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B2:D2,"y")>0, LEFT(IF(Sheet2!B2="y",Sheet2!B$1&", ","")&IF(Sheet2!C2="y",Sheet2!C$1&", ","")&IF(Sheet2!D2="y",Sheet2!D$1&", ",""),LEN(IF(Sheet2!B2="y",Sheet2!B$1&", ","")&IF(Sheet2!C2="y",Sheet2!C$1&", ","")&IF(Sheet2!D2="y",Sheet2!D$1&", ",""))-2),"")
```